# How i can implement the Service

Tags: android

I develop an Android Project in which I have to parse the RSS feeds. So I parse this feeds over the internet at the time of startup of application. But my problem is when parsing is executing then program will wait for long time. So i want to implement the Service, which will do the processing is  in background. How I can do this?

My code for XML parsing is:

```
try 
        {
            feeditemshelper = new FeedItemsHelper();
            RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
            Element channelElement = root.getChild("channel");
            Element itemElement = channelElement.getChild("item");
            itemElement.getChild("title").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void end(String body)
                {
                    LHParser.feeditemshelper.setTitle(body);
                }
            });
            Element descElement = itemElement.getChild("description");
            descElement.getChild("image").setEndTextElementListener(
                    new EndTextElementListener()
                    {
                        public void end(String body) 
                        {
                            LHParser.feeditemshelper.setImage(body);
                        }
                    });
            descElement.getChild("text").setEndTextElementListener(
                    new EndTextElementListener()
                    {
                        public void end(String body) 
                        {
                            dflag++;
                            LHParser.feeditemshelper.setDescription(body,dflag);
                        }
                    });
            itemElement.getChild("pubDate").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void end(String body)
                {
                    LHParser.feeditemshelper.setPubDate(body);
                }
            });
            try 
            {
                Xml.parse(
                        getInputStreamFromUrl("http://www.bjp.org/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=12&format=raw"),
                        Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to get your program to run as a service? How did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an AsyncTask. There is a nice example on the [Android Dev Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
Your parsing logic needs to be done in the doInBackground method.

It will not block the UI as doInBackGround is executed in a seperate background thread.

You can show/hide a progress dialog in the onPreExecute/onPostExecute methods.
(The onPreExecute/onPostExecute methods are run on the UI thread so there you can interact with the UI and notifiy the user - if you wish - when the processing starts/finishes).

Answer (score 1):

Devang. you can use AsyncTask for load data in background for get detail for it so go link which is given by ddewaele. and you want know about service then [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).